# remove help pages from an ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When you create a new Web API Project (MVC 4) it automatically creates the Help Pages for the API. Any ideas how can I remove the ASP.NET Web API help pages?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. Delete the folder called `HelpPage` under `Areas`
2. Remove the package called `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` from your `pacakges.config` file.
3. Remove the following line from `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` file
   `@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)`

Comment: One question: what happens when you remove it from packages.config? is it automatically removes (the assemblies) ?

Comment: HelpPage nuget package doesn't install any dlls...it only creates the HelpPage area folder content...

Comment: Don't remove the line from packages.config. Use the 'Manage NuGet Packages' dialog or enter the following command in the 'Package Manager Console': uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage . That will remove the assemblies from your project.

Answer (score 10):

As a more recommended solution to Kiran's solution is to go simply to Nuget Package Manager and remove the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`.

This is going to remove all the necessary files including those in the areas folder.

Comment: It removes all classes and styles but the folders. Those must be removed manually from Solution explorer.